# Cannot connect with SIP using Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip

I configured SIP connection with Asterisk. Server is running successfully but when i try to connect sip with X-Lite. Its giving Sip Error 408.

```
disallow=all                    ; First disallow all codecs
allow=ulaw                      ; Allow codecs in order of preference


externip = **.**.***.***; Address that we're going to put in outbound SIP
                            ; messages if we're behind a NAT


;localnet=192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0; All RFC 1918 addresses are local networks
localnet=10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0     ; Also RFC1918
;localnet=172.16.0.0/12         ; Another RFC1918 with CIDR notation
;localnet=169.254.0.0/255.255.0.0 ;Zero conf local network


nat=route                               ; Global NAT settings  (Affects all peers and users)
                            ; yes = Always ignore info and assume NAT
                            ; no = Use NAT mode only according to RFC3581 (;rport)
                            ; never = Never attempt NAT mode or RFC3581 support
                            ; route = Assume NAT, don't send rport
                            ; (work around more UNIDEN bugs)
```

This is my sip.conf file

and my extensions.conf is:

```
exten => *98,1,VoiceMailMain
exten => *98,2,Hangup
```

Please check the details and help me to connect. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asterisk 13 then you should configure the extensions in **pjsip.conf** (and not in sip.conf file). Asterisk 13 have moved to pjsip.

Otherwise the error code 408 means "Request Timeout" so most probably X-Lite doesn't receive any answer for the REGISTER request. Double check your IP/port/NAT configurations.

If still doesn't then you should have a look at the logs.
(Enable logs by sipdebug=yes and in logger.conf set the Verbose config to "notice,warning,error,debug,verbose,dtmf" below the [logfiles] section)

Comment: Just note, asterisk 13 does have chan_sip as well chan_pjsip. But only one of them can bind() with port 5060.